# Confidence interval does not display on barplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I am wanting to display the confidence interval for each bar in my plot, but they do not seem to show. I have two dataframes, and I am displaying the average of the `NUMBER_GIRLS` column in my plot from both dataframes.

For example, consider the two dataframes (shown below).

- `schools_north_df`

```
ID     NAME     NUMBER_GIRLS
----------------------------
1     SCHOOL_1       32
2     SCHOOL_2       12
3     SCHOOL_3       26
```

- `schools_south_df`

```
ID     NAME     NUMBER_GIRLS
----------------------------
1     SCHOOL_1       56
2     SCHOOL_2       33
3     SCHOOL_3       34
```

Therefore, I have used this code (shown below) to plot my barplot with the confidence intervals showing for each bar - but when plotting it, the confidence interval does not show up.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('North', 'South')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
avg_girls = [schools_north_df[NUMBER_GIRLS].mean(), schools_south_df[NUMBER_GIRLS].mean()]

sns.barplot(y_pos, avg_girls, ci=95)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.title('Average Number of Girls')

plt.show()
```

If anyone could kindly help me and indicate what is wrong with my code. I really need the confidence interval to display on my barplot.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want seaborn to display the confidence intervals, you need to let seaborn aggregate the data by itself (that is to say, provide the raw data instead of calculating the mean yourself).

I would create a new dataframe with an extra column (`region`) to indicate whether the data are from the "north" or the "south" and then request seaborn to plot `NUMBER_GIRLS` vs `region`:

```py
df = pd.concat([schools_north_df.assign(region='North'), schools_south_df.assign(region='South')])
```

output:

> ```
>   ID      NAME  NUMBER_GIRLS region
> 0   1  SCHOOL_1            32  North
> 1   2  SCHOOL_2            12  North
> 2   3  SCHOOL_3            26  North
> 0   1  SCHOOL_1            56  South
> 1   2  SCHOOL_2            33  South
> 2   3  SCHOOL_3            34  South
> ```

plot:

```py
sns.barplot(data=df, x='region', y='NUMBER_GIRLS', ci=95)
```

[image]